# Book about two people in different worlds that are linked but only one of them knows it

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this last year in the back of a different book, and have been looking around for it a bit. I would love if someone could help me find it

It’s a fantasy(?) book where it starts with someone who can feel and see everything the other person does, but they are in different worlds. It than transitions to the perspective of someone in that other world (not sure if same people) where they need to make sure that someone doesn’t get hurt, even by a splinter because if they do it will summon(?) something.

Edit for more context: The way I remember them talking about getting hurt is that someone needed to go through and pick up all the splinters on the floor because even one of those would be enough, it may have been that any break in the skin would cause something to happen, also it was  a preview but I don’t remember anything about the actual book it was in.also it is a more recent one, at the time I read the preview I don’t even know if the book was out yet. Also after taking a look at it, it doesn’t seem to be the Apprentice Adept series. Hope this helps clear some things up!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   When you say you read it "in the back of a different book" do you mean you read a preview chapter from this book?  Can you remember anything about the book you read it in?

Answer (score 4):

Are you speaking of the series The Apprentice Adept by Piers Anthony? The book where they find out about one another is Juxtaposition, the third novel in the series after Split Infinity and Blue Adept.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You can improve you answer by showing how this matches all the details of the question, like the part about how getting hurt might invoke a summoning.